# How to restore database from /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, recovery, restore, disaster-recovery

I have a database folder from a crashed server called gain_wordpress. I'm trying to put that database on a new server but I'm not able to do it successfully. I don't have a .sql dump, all I have is the database folder from a past crashed server with ibdata and the 2 log files.

I copied the gain_wordpress folder to /var/lib/mysql on the new server but when I do a > `show tables` on the database I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './gain_wordpress/' (errno: 13)
```

I also changed the permission of the folder and did a chown mysql:mysql gain_wordpress -R and it still didn't take care of the problem.

What is the best way to recover gain_wordpress. Do I need to replace any of the ibdata or the logfiles? What is the best way? I have the corresponding `.frm`, `.MYD` and `.MYI` files for each table. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure the ownership and privileges are correct for the directory, you can use the following commands to set it right:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/ --your mysql user may have different name, if its different you need to change it [mysql:mysql] as needed 
chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

note: `-R`: recursive fir the directory and all its contents.

Comment: The permissions for the `mysql` user and group on file level are generally `-rw-rw----` which corresponds to `0660`. I'd perform the chmod from the `gain_wordpress` directory downwards (`chmod -R 0660 /var/lib/mysql/gain_wordpress`).